# Is it true that every McDonald's branch had a bunker in case of war?

Tags: united-states, war, mcdonalds

About 10-15 years ago, I heard rumors that in 20 century every branch of McDonald in America had a bunker in case of war with USSR. Bunkers are placed in this way so that they can easily be found by residents - as everyone is well aware of where the nearest McDonald's is.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FHkydNwI5UE) is an example of video (Russian, with English subtitles) covering this topic.

Is it true?

Comment: Rumors heard 10-15 years ago are hardly notable, and a claim needs to be notable to be on-topic here. If you could come up with some reference to those rumors, that would help your question.

Comment: @DevSolar added video on topic.

Comment: I just found that video myself - it only has a couple of thousand views. Can we do better?

Comment: It was the only place I can see anyone making the claim.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't provide anything better than Google can. Especially considering that rumors came from the times when I hadn't Internet access at all.

Comment: The video doesn't just claim that all McDonalds have an underground nuclear bunker, but that the company is also a front, and was created for the purpose of hiding bunkers in plain sight.

Comment: Has anyone else heard this claim before? At the moment, it just seems to be a weird joke that no-one is taking seriously.

Comment: No, though I can only cite my personal experience, having (some years ago) worked for a construction company that built restaurants for McDonalds (and other chains).  Every one of the several dozen I was involved with was built on a concrete slab foundation.

Comment: This is clearly bunk because everyone knows that fallout shelters were designated and marked.

Comment: @jamesqf As someone who reviewed some blueprints for a recent remodel of a McDonald... I concur.  Slabs are usually faster and cheaper to build.

Comment: "You will need to construct a network of bunkers, so that every resident could reach it at any moment." - "Within the US there are over 15,000 McDonald's restaurant." So, each of the bunkers has to accommodate about 20,000 people. That's one big NOPE. Even the [Greenbrier bunker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Greek_Island) only held about a thousand people.

Comment: @jamesqf, some of older ones were built with a basement.  There was a bit in the local newspaper recently about remodeling the city's very first McDonalds, and that they needed to fill in the basement as part of the process.

Comment: @Mazura, at the end of the movie they claim that the bunkers can hold 100K people, so not all of the U.S population.

Comment: @Mark: Sure, some may have been built with basements.  Some are even built inside other structures, like shopping malls.  But even one counterexample is sufficient to disprove the claim that EVERY McDonalds has a bunker.  Also, my direct experience is limited to ones built in the western US during the late '70s.  (And for the OP, I have absolutely no idea where the nearest McDonalds is.)

Comment: @jamesqf - If the used a concrete slab as the foundation, then I guess you have no evidence that government contracted mole men didn't use a secret tunnelling machine to dig the bunker after construction of the main building.  Also you don't know where your nearest McDs is, god help you, how are you supposed to get a proper balanced diet?

Comment: @Code Gorilla: Well, that's true.  But since I also did repair & remodel work on existing ones, all I can say is that those mole men concealed the entrance really well :-)